# Creating my own music server

Tags: music, media

The 256 GB SSD in my laptop is too small to contain my entire music library. What I want is to build my own music server, which will stay at home, online, from which I'll be able to stream music on demand to my mac laptop and iphone wherever I am.

What technologies can be used for this? I'm willing to use whatever server setup this takes - OS X / linux, whatever.

Bonus points if I can also use it for my photos in the same manner.

Answer (score 3):

[Plex](http://www.plexapp.com) or [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org) sound like good fits for you.  Both are client/server solutions and can be installed on the big 3 operating systems.  They both have excellent desktop, web and smart phone clients.

Plex does everything you'd expect from a media center:- music/video/photos.  Subsonic focuses on music and does it pretty well.

If music is your priority I'd opt for Subsonic.